# TimeShift not storing snapshots and not using the correct drive

Tags: hard-drive, 22.04, snapshot, timeshift

I use Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS

Yesterday I installed TimeShift to create a backup of my system. Once installed, I clicked the 'create' button, the process finished, but the supposedly created copy does not appear on the screen. Snapshot not showing:

[image]

I restarted the computer, and it still does not appear.

This is what I selected as backup location:

[image]

Plus, the 933GB remains the same. After restarting the computer, I lost access to my hard drive, as seen in the second image. Second image:

[image]

There should be another HDD with the letter 'D' under 'Computer', since that is how I labeled my HDD, when I click 'search' in TimeShift to search for the created backups, it takes me to a location inside the 'Computer' disk, even though I told it several times to save them in 'D'. Snapshots location:

[image]

I want to have access to my D hard drive, and I want the backups to be saved there. How can I fix this?

I tried reinstalling TimeShift and repeating the process. I didn't try playing with the permissions on my drives because I already messed up in the past.

Comment: Drive letters aren't really used in Linux.

Comment: I know there is no "D". I called my HDD "D" And I have no access to it now, before I installed TimeShift I did. And now, even if I uninstall it, I don't have access any more. I edited and added what I specified as backup location

Comment: Your question has a few references to a D drive maybe you want to remove these.

Comment: @user68186 I am using rsync

Comment: @David Yes, because I labeled my hdd "D". That is what I talk about a D drive

Comment: Just be aware that TimeShift mounts your snapshot location at a mount point such as /run/timeshift/backup/timeshift when it runs. So check what is mounted where. How do you mount sda1, the partition you call D? What does `lsblk` show? Did you go all the way through the settings process and did you get any errors when it ran?